# vba excel summarize cells

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I want to put in choose range in one column where i put sum formula in each cells which has bg color RGB(252,228,214) and this sum will summarize cells above until it find cell that has bg color. so it summarize only cells with no bgcolor between two colored cells? i need VBA code for Excel. Please help me? i want to work only with F column and put sum formula in colored cells

[image]

i explained above all

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you run into problems getting it to work?

Comment: i tried ChatGPT but i cannot give right instruction to it.

Answer (score 2):

try updated code sum formula inside the cell with interior color with address of cell below it with no interior color

```
Sub BuildSumFormulas()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim formulaRange
Dim formulaRGB

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row


For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(252, 228, 214) Then
        If formulaRange = "" Then
            Set formulaRGB = ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, "F")
            formulaRange = "=SUM("
        Else
            formulaRGB.Value = Left(formulaRange, Len(formulaRange) - 1) & ")"
            Set formulaRGB = ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, "F")
            formulaRange = "=SUM("
        End If
    Else
        formulaRange = formulaRange & cell.Address & ","
        If cell.Row = lastRow Then
            formulaRGB.Value = Left(formulaRange, Len(formulaRange) - 1) & ")"
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: i don't want to put results in G column. I want to put formula sum in colored cells. and this sum should summarize cells that don't have bgcolor it is like total sum on each colored cells

Comment: @AlmazBakirov updated code above